# Android recyclerview-selection single item only

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, selection

I implemented the `recyclerView-Selection` API with a single selection with the following code:

```
selectionTracker = SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>(SELECTION_ID,recyclerView,
Adapter.MessagesItemKeyProvider(1),
Adapter.MessagesItemLookup(messagesRecyclerView),
StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()).withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.createSelectSingleAnything()).build()
```

Now, my `recyclerView` is only a single item that can be selectable.

When selecting another item, instead of replacing the selection I need to clear current selection only?

Comment: you want to select single item on select item after last selecting item want to remove from selection ?

Comment: I want clear selection when selecting non selected items

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow single selection, you just have to provide a [SelectionPredicate](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/selection/SelectionTracker.SelectionPredicate) into your SelectionTracker.Builder.

```java
final SelectionTracker<Long> tracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<>(
    "my-selection-id",
    recyclerView,
    provider,
    detailLookup,
    StorageStrategy.createLongStorage())
    .withSelectionPredicate(new SelectionTracker.SelectionPredicate<Long>() {
        @Override
        public boolean canSetStateForKey(@NonNull Long key, boolean nextState) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canSetStateAtPosition(int position, boolean nextState) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canSelectMultiple() {
            return false; // Set to false to allow single selecting
        }
    })
    .build();
```

Comment: Even not need to be implemented, It can be achieved by SelectionPredicates.<Long>createSelectSingleAnything()